# Why is preg_replace not removing space after a quote

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, php-5.5

Given the code:

```
$SearchWords=['\'"','GOLF','FACILITIES','IN','CANADA','\'"'];

$s[1] = 'SUB2,DETRAN=("';
$s[1] .= implode(' ', array_filter($SearchWords));
$s[1] .= '"*) OR A=((';
//remove space after an opening quote mark
$s[1] = preg_replace("/('['\"])[ ](\S.*)([ ]\1)/U", "$1$2$3", $s[1]);
//remove space before closing quote mark
$s[1] = preg_replace("/('['\"])(\S.*)[ ](\1)/U", "$1$2$3", $s[1]);
```

The result should be `SUB2,DETRAN=("'"GOLF FACILITIES IN CANADA'""*) OR A=((` instead I get `SUB2,DETRAN=("'" GOLF FACILITIES IN CANADA '""*) OR A=((` (notice the space is still there before GOLF and after CANADA).  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  I have tried with and without the spaces in character classes.

PHP version is 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you're using pattern in double quotes and using single escaped `\1`. It need to be `\\1` when in double quotes.

Use:

```
$s[1] = preg_replace("/('['\"]) (\S.*)( \\1)/U", "$1$2$3", $s[1]);
$s[1] = preg_replace("/('['\"])(\S.*) (\\1)/U", "$1$2$3", $s[1]);

echo $s[1];
//=> SUB2,DETRAN=("'"GOLF FACILITIES IN CANADA'""*) OR A=((
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! That worked.  I completely overlooked that php needed the backslash escaped for it to pass it to the preg engine.